# Is the adjective in this phrase in right order?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english

The name of the building that collapsed in Florida USA:

> ***Champlain Towers South***,

raised a question inside my English learner mind. It feels like a description of noun *South*. Again in my learner mind it would have made more sense if to say:

> South Champlain Towers

Then I would reason: ***Tower*** is the building itself ***Champlain*** is the name of it and it is located ***South***. Does this make sense?

Comment: There really are no rules for names.

Comment: 1) *North Champlain Towers,* 2) *Champlain North Towers,* and 3) *Champlain Towers North* are all perfectly credible names for a tower block. Arguably the last of those (and to a lesser extent the second) might more strongly imply there's also a corresponding *South* building, but imho they could all be used regardless of whether *any* other such related buildings exist. That's to say, "South" might be relative to the general location *Champlain*, OR it might be relative to one or more *other* "Champlain Towers" buildings, OR it may have no such implications at all.

Comment: Cardinal points of the compass often do come last in names for some reason.

Comment: @Fumble, I would say that putting the relative discriminator before or after the compound noun is common; I'm not sure I've ever seen it inserted into the compound noun. Can you point to an example (that doesn't, e.g., use, "Champlain South" as the already-established name of the surrounding neighborhood)?